# Voter Eligibility Requirements

Tags: discussion, election

Who is eligible to vote in the Election of Moderators? I've checked the existing tagged questions and the Help Center and can find no mention of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Users with more than 150 reputation can vote in the election, according to the sidebar on [the 'election' tab](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/election/1?tab=election):

> Any community member with **150** reputation may vote in the election. Each voter may select up to three candidates. Please make your selections in order of preference, with the most desirable candidate as first choice.

We're currently in the 'nomination' phase, where no voting is allowed. On Monday, we'll move on to the election phase.